# How to use partitioned day tables in big query view to reduce cost when added in datastudio

Tags: google-bigquery, partitioning, looker-studio

I  add a partitioned table (like tableYYYYMMDD) to datastudio dashboard but I need to add more information, I don't know how I can maintain the same cost that partitioned table but using view...
I want to add view in datastudio but pay only for the day that we filter (not retrieving dat range from view because it increase the cost).

Anyone can help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a pseudo column on your view:

```
SELECT *, _TABLE_SUFFIX as pseudo_column
FROM `SOURCE`
```

And when you run a query on your view you should do:

```
 SELECT *
    FROM `VIEW` WHERE pseudo_column = "DESIRED DATE (yyyymmdd)"
```

I hope it helps

Comment: HI, thanks for your help, how I can send the date parameter to the view from datastudio? Normally I add a date filter in datastudio and automaticallý it will be related to the partitioned table date but I don't know how can I send this date filter to the condition of the view...

Comment: Roger, have you tried creating a filter using the pseudo column?